# Integrating Puppet (v3.8) with Hashicorp Vault as CA?

Tags: puppet, distributed, ca, hashicorp-vault

I've been putting of on making my Puppet master redundant for quite a while now, but it's starting to become an issue now. So I'm starting to put this on a higher importance issue.

Although making the master itself highly available isn't much of a problem (I've already running it behind a load balancer in anticipation of making it HA).

But the problem is the CA "part" of Puppet. I guess it would be (theoretically) possible to put the Puppet master directory on a shared filesystem and have all Puppet masters use that as their storage.

But I have need for a CA for other purposes anyway, so I've been, for the last year (on and off), looking into Vault.

From the documentation and the information I've seen so far about it, it could solve a whole bunch of problems for me, not just the distributed CA part.

It can acts as a CA, but is there any way to integrate that into Puppet? As in, having Vault acts as a CA for the Puppet master(s)?

PS. Many seems to use Puppet in a masterless capacity, and that would of course negate this CA problem, but for various reasons, I don't want to do that (respect the decision please).

Comment: The easier approach would be to use Puppet's CA and integrate Vault with that. Also consider upgrading to a non-obsolete version of Puppet.

Comment: That won't solve the problem of having the CA highly available.

Comment: You didn't mention that as a problem. Why aren't you able to do a HA CA?

Comment: Quote: "But the problem is the CA "part" of Puppet. I guess it would be (theoretically) possible to put the Puppet master directory on a shared filesystem and have all Puppet masters use that as their storage."

Comment: Using a shared FS for something like this .. Well, I don't feel entirely comfortable with that. Must be a better way. And since Vault is needed (elsewhere) anyway, it would be nice to have that as the CA. That way I can remove three CAs with one in the company.

Comment: So is your question about having a HA CA or integrating Vault with Puppet?

Comment: Both. And reducing three CAs in the company to one.

Comment: If it's not possible to "replace" the internal Puppet CA with (something like) Vault, then another idea (just spitballing here) could be to disable the Puppet CA and have the bootstrap script (that runs on ALL instances when they boot/start up for the first time) request a cert for the instance (from Vault for example) and then put that in the place of the Puppet client cert location.